# IP number to filename

Tags: php, ip, md5

I use PHP and get an IP number. As a kind of log I convert them to something unique and save them as files, currently as MD5.

I'm not sure that it's the best way. Do you know a better way?

- I'm aware of that converting an IP address like this is not bulletproof.
- It should be able to handle IPV4 and IPV6 (maybe others if any)
- The filename should be [unique based on ip number].txt
- The filename can't be random, they need to be calculated.
- Speed and uniqueness are high priority.

Comment: Why use a file(s) and not a DB?

Comment: Why not just do the ip address as the string? Does it need to be secretized?

Comment: @JakeParis Yes, I need to use it as a filename. A filename does no allow all possible characters.

Comment: @chris85 I'm using a flat file CMS called Kirby and making a plugin for it.

Comment: @JensTörnell how about just sanitizing the IP (removing unsafe characters) and then using it for the filename?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of using a format like ip4-x-x-x-x.log and ip6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-whatever.log

You can strip the first 4 characters later on and str_replace the - back to dots and double colons.

You could use md5, but then you would need to store the hash somewhere as you can`t reverse hashes. If you are worried about privacy then you could use it however, as long as you know the address for the log you want to lookup.

Comment: I don't care about privacy here. Reading on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address ::/128 also seems to be IP numbers. So I need to take care of / as well. That's what I fear, that I miss some convert some not allowed characters. Do you know any more characters that could be in an IP number?

Comment: You can also use ip2long in case you want to be sure that ip addresses can be converted to filenames. There is a ipToHex function in the comments: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php#82013 There is also ip2long6: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php#94477